# Delphi and C++, dll importing

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I have a DLL, with exported function:

```
int HCalculator::CalculateMC(const char* h, const char* b, const char* d, __int64 numberOfTrials, double* results)
```

How to import that function in Delphi project?

It seems to be like:

```
function CalculateMC(h, b, d: PChar; numberOfTrials: int64; results: ???): integer; stdcall; external 'MYDLL.DLL';
```

But what about an array of double? How to write it down? And how should I call that function?

Comment: That's a C++ member function. You need a C style function. What's the calling convention? You sure it is `stdcall`? Also, it's impossible to say how to call it with this information. Only you can possibly know. For example, `double* results` could be used to return a single value or an array. Which is it?

Comment: results should be an array of double.

Answer (score 1):

The `results` parameter is an array of doubles. Suppose, for sake of argument, that the array has `numberOfTrials` elements. Then you would call the DLL like this:

```
function CalculateMC(h, b, d: PChar; numberOfTrials: int64; 
    results: PDouble): integer; stdcall; external 'MYDLL.DLL';
.....
var
  returnVal: integer;
  results: array of Double;
.....
SetLength(results, numberOfTrials);
returnVal := CalculateMC(h, b, d, numberOfTrials, @results[0]);
```

One major problem that I see is that your C++ function appears to be a member function. You could call that from Delphi by added an extra parameter to `CalculateMC`, before all other parameters, which contained a pointer to the C++ object instance. But you would will need a way of getting hold of that instance. And obviously you would have to modify the declaration of `CalculateMC` in your Delphi code. Presumably your DLL would export a function that returned a newly created instance.

Another possible issue is that you have specified `stdcall` in your Delphi import but not done so in the C++ code. If you are compiling the C++ with the option to use `stdcall` for your functions then the interfaces will match. Otherwise you cannot call this code from Delphi at all because MS `thiscall` has no direct equivalent in Delphi. I would add an explicit `__stdcall` to your C++ code.

Comment: "You could call that from Delphi..."  I disagree.  The `thiscall` calling convention used by member functions passes the `this` pointer in ECX, which is not where `stdcall` places the first parameter.

Comment: @BenVoigt Never mind the `this` pointer, all params would be off if there was a mismatch. I was assuming that the C++ DLL was compiled to use `stdcall` for this function. Clearly calling conventions have match. Beyond that you would need to provide the `this` pointer as an extra param no matter which convention was in use. Anyway, I've added a paragraph discussing calling convention now. P.S. How's the weather in Houston at the moment, I'll be visiting in a couple of weeks!

Comment: @Ben, I've written code to work around that problem. See my import units for the [windowless rich-edit control](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/windowless-rtf), where Microsoft neglected to use stdcall for the interfaces.

Comment: @David: With Microsoft C++, non-static member functions all use `thiscall` and ordinary functions use either `cdecl` or `stdcall`.  I don't think the calling convention of member functions can be changed no matter how many keywords you use.  BTW the temperature here is quite nice, we have had a mixture of sunny days with overcast and rain.  Shorts and t-shirts are definitely indicated (perfect for sunny days, and dry out quicker on the other...)  If you use my name as a URL you should be able to find my contact info.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not sure that's right. Have a read of this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx

Comment: @David: that page says `__stdcall` can be used on non-static member functions, but the calling convention doesn't provide any way to pass `this`.  If accurate, the combination would be useless, so this is probably a documentation bug.

Comment: @BenVoigt No I don't think so. Think of how COM interfaces are declared. They all have `__stdcall` on the virtual methods. And what happens is that the `this` pointer is passed as an extra, implicit, parameter, before all other parameters. But I can't find the documentation of that (yet).

Comment: @David: It's a documentation bug that it doesn't explain how `this` is passed.

Comment: @ben ok, I'm with you now and agree